# Ejecutar script de forma automática

Tags: r

Supongamos que tenemos una carpeta  llamada "prueba" en el escritorio con dos csv

```
data1 <- data.frame(x1 = 1:5, x2 = 1:5)
data2 <- data.frame(x1 = 6:10, x2 = 6:10)
setwd("~/Escritorio/prueba")

write.csv2(data1, "data1.csv", row.names = FALSE)      
write.csv2(data2, "data2.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Abro el Rstudio, cargo los datos, hago una operación cualquiera, como meter los datos en una lista, guardo el resultado en la carpeta y cierro el Rstudio.

```
lista1 <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")     
lista <- lapply(lista1, read.csv2)   
write.csv2(lista, "lista.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

¿Cómo lo hago para dejar el script en la carpeta, como si fuera un ejecutable, de forma que al pinchar en el script ejecute la acción y no tenga que abrir Rstudio?

No sé si se hace de forma diferente en windows y en linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rstudio es un IDE, siempre por debajo, se ejecuta el interprete R. Por esto siempre podremos automatizar cualquier Script llamandolo directamente desde el interprete:

Supongamos que tenemos un `mi_script.R` en cierta carpeta, desde la terminal o linea de comando, parados en la carpeta, podremos hacer:

```
Rscript mi_script.R
```

o bien

```
R CMD BATCH mi_script.R
```

---

Comentarios

1. Obviamente `Rscript` o `Rscript.exe` al igual que `R` deben estar en el path, sino, eventualmente habrá que invocarlos con el path de su ubcación.
2. La primer alternativa muestra toda impresión por la salida estándar, en cambio `R CMD BATCH mi_script.R` redirige automáticamente toda salida por pantalla a un archivo `mi_script.Rout'.

Automatizar luego, la ejecución mencionada dependerá de SO, por ejemplo:

#### Linux

Podemos agregar un "shebang" al script, en la primer línea indicamos cual es el interprete que procesará el script: `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript`, nos falta hacer ejecutable el script:

```
chmod +x mi_script.R
```

Con esto, podremos simplemente ejecutarlo mediante: `./mi_sript.R` o dependiendo de software de escritorio, se podrá hacer dobleclick como cualquier otro módulo ejecutable del sistema.

#### Windows

Lo más sencillo es crear un archivo con extensión `.BAT` e ingresar la línea de comando a ajecutar:

```
<path a los binarios de R>\Rscript.exe mi_script.R
```

---

#### Enlaces interesates:

- [Ayuda de `Rscript`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rscript)

Answer (score 2):

Si el script está andando bien (i.e. no es necesario supervisarlo/editarlo para que funcione) no es necesario que uses Rstudio, que es muy lindo pero muy pesado. Puedes usar directamente R desde la consola, es mucho más rápido.

La opción más simple, que debería funcionar tanto para Linux como para Windows  es usar la utilidad `Rscript`. Esa utilidad se instala cuando se instala `R`, así que ya deberías tenerla disponible. Si está en el path global es tan simple como ubicarte en la carpeta en la que está el script y usar

```
Rscript nombre_del_script.R
```

Si no está en path entonces deberías agregarlo o ir a la ubicación donde está el binario `Rscript.exe` y desde ahí hacer la llamada al script usando el path completo. Es más complicado.

`Rscript` permite más opciones, como pasar argumentos desde la consola al script que se va a ejecutar. Pero el uso básico es este.

En Linux también podría poner esta líneaen un script de Bash y hacerlo ejecutable, para poder hacerlo andar con un doble click. Inclusive podrías crear una tarea en cron para que se ejecute automáticamente.

En Windows seguramente también se puede, pero no sabría como.